# Dropdown filter is showing incorrect result in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The display should show the result as per the values selected in checkboxes and dropdown. While checkboxes are working well and displaying result accordingly, the dropdown on selection do not show the correct display. It only shows the display as per the last clicked value and not the current one.

Also the displays are incorrect in case I select dropdown first and then apply checkbox filter.

Here is my code:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import BookData from "../data/bookData.json";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import { Checkbox, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import "../style/search.css";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";

const BookDisplay = (props) => {
  const allBooks = BookData.book.map((books) => {
    return books;
  });

  const [edition, setEdition] = useState(""); //  dropdown state

  const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState([]);

  const [filteredResult, setFilteredResult] = useState(allBooks);

  //Building DropDown Filter

  const uniqueEditions = [
    ...new Set(
      BookData.book.map((allEditions) => {
        return allEditions.edition;
      })
    )
  ]; // filters out all the unique edition of the books

  const editionDropdown = uniqueEditions.map((edition) => (
    <option value={edition}>{edition}</option>
  ));

  editionDropdown.unshift(<option value="">All Editions</option>);

  //Making a checkbox

  const uniqueGenre = [
    ...new Set(
      BookData.book.map((bookGenre) => {
        return bookGenre.genre;
      })
    )
  ];

  //adding checked =false falue for every object

  uniqueGenre.map((obj) => ({ ...obj, Active: false }));

  // filtering result based on checkbox value
  const handleCheckBox = (filter) => {
    const newFilter = activeFilter.includes(filter)
      ? activeFilter.filter((f) => {
          return f !== filter;
        })
      : [...activeFilter, filter];

    setActiveFilter(newFilter);
    console.log(allBooks);
    const filteredList =
      newFilter.length > 0
        ? allBooks.filter((item) => newFilter.includes(item.genre))
        : allBooks;
    console.log(filteredList);
    setFilteredResult(filteredList);
    console.log("filteredresult in checkbox", filteredResult);
  };

  //handling dropdown change

  const handleDropDownChange = (event, name) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setEdition({
      [name]: event.target.value
    });
    const searchedBooks = filteredResult.filter((filteredBooks) => {
      return Object.entries(edition).every(([key, value]) => {
        if (!value) return true;
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        return filteredBooks[key] === value;
      });
    });

    setFilteredResult(searchedBooks);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="Search">
        <label>Edition</label>
        <select
          defaultValue={edition}
          onChange={(e) => handleDropDownChange(e, "edition")}
        >
          {editionDropdown}
        </select>{" "}
      </form>
      <Grid>
        {uniqueGenre.map((genre, index) => (
          <FormGroup key={index}>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox name={genre} />}
              label={genre}
              value={genre}
              checked={genre.Active}
              onChange={() => handleCheckBox(genre)}
              color="Primary"
            />
          </FormGroup>
        ))}

        <Grid></Grid>
        <Grid xs={9}>
          <div className="container">
            {filteredResult.map((bookData) => (
              <Card key={bookData.id}>
                <CardActions>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography className="avatar">
                      <div>
                        <img src={bookData.imgUrl} alt="img" />
                      </div>
                      <span>
                        <u> {bookData.title}</u>
                      </span>
                    </Typography>
                    <br />
                    <div className="book-Info">
                      <Typography>
                        <b>Price:</b> {bookData.price}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography>
                        <b>Author:</b>
                        {bookData.author}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography>
                        <b>Year:</b>
                        {bookData.year_written}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography>
                        <b>Edition:</b> {bookData.edition}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography>
                        <b>Genre:</b> {bookData.genre}
                      </Typography>
                    </div>
                  </CardContent>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookDisplay;
```

[Code Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-lewin-jwir9?file=/src/components/BookDisplay.js:0-4738)

Comment: change this code by (sample)[https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-hopper-om6k5?file=/src/components/BookDisplay.js]

Comment: The issue still persists. If I select an edition first and then checks any checkboxes , it will give me be the books of all the editions belonging to that genre instead of that particular edition. Also the lag in display of select still persists. It is still showing the display according to last selected edition instead of the current selected value

Comment: yes.a functions for filtter convert to one function.

Comment: I am unable to  figure out how to fix this dropdown based result

Comment: check [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-hopper-om6k5?file=/src/components/BookDisplay.js)

Comment: now the checkbox filters do not seem to be working. it was working perfectly earlier. The dropdown still shows the delay in display